# (Discord.py) My program cannot add value to my sqlite3 file

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make my bot send a message to a channel, and when the user reacts with a certain emoji, the bot will insert the ID of the voice channel that the user is in, the ID of the server  and the number of the theme that the user has chosen.

Below is my code for it:

```
global conn
global c
conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
c = conn.cursor()

@bot.command() 
async def assign(ctx):
    try:
        global getid
        global getguild
        global gettheme
        
        getid = str(ctx.author.voice.channel.id)
        print (getid)
        getguild = str(ctx.author.guild.id)
        print (getguild)
        global Ftext
        Ftext = ""
        correct = 0
        global Flist
        

        titlename = "Please select a theme"
        embed = discord.Embed(title = titlename, description = Ftext.strip(), color = 0xff6868)
        embed.add_field(name = "1. Lofi", value = "Lofi", inline = False)
        embed.add_field(name = "Gaming✨", value = "NCS, EDM", inline = False)
        Flist = await ctx.send(embed = embed)
        await Flist.add_reaction("")
        await Flist.add_reaction("✨")

    except:
        await ctx.send('Please join a channel first')
```

This is the part where the bot sends the embed message and adds reactions to it.

I have stated three variables:

**getid** which is the ID of the voice channel,

**getguild** which is the ID of the server,

and **gettheme** which is the theme for the channel.

Below is the code for detecting the user's reaction and adding the three variables to the database.

```
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, users):
    if users.bot == 1:
        pass
    else:
        try:
            await Flist.delete()
        except:
            pass
        else:
            if str(reaction.emoji) == '':
                await reaction.message.channel.send("Set the theme to lo-fi. Channel id = "+str(getid))
                gettheme = '1'
                print(gettheme)
                c.execute("INSERT INTO channel_data (id, guild_id, theme) VALUES (?,?,?)", (getid, getguild, gettheme))
                
            elif str(reaction.emoji) == '✨':
                await reaction.message.channel.send("Set the theme to NCS. Channel id = "+str(getid))
                gettheme = '2'
                print(gettheme)
                c.execute("INSERT INTO channel_data (id, guild_id, theme) VALUES (?,?,?)", (getid, getguild, gettheme))
```

As seen in the code, there are three columns in the sqlite3 file which are id, guild_id and theme. All three of them are stated as STRING.

However, when I run the code, I don't get any errors but no data is added to the database when I check it using a DB browser.

Also, I have tried adding data to the same file by writing another simple program,

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("INSERT INTO channel_data (id, guild_id, theme) VALUES (?,?,?)", ('1', '2', '3'))

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

and this works perfectly fine.

How should I resolve this? I don't get any error from this, so I am not really sure how I should fix it.

Comment: Have you defined `getid` and `getguild`?

Comment: Using global variable is not recommended. Think about what would happen if a user runs assign and another user runs assign before the first user has reacted. You should get everything you need from arguments to `on_reaction_add`